# how throw first enter trigger animate angular6

Tags: angular, animation

This is my animation:

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Routage } from './routage';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('startCentre', [
      state('start', style({
        opacity: 0.7,
      })
      ),
      state('end', style({
        opacity: 1,
      })
      ),
      transition('start => end', animate('2000ms ease-in')),
    ])
  ]

})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  anim :any= true; //à true on commence avec une opacité faible

  get quelEtatCentre() {
    console.log("etat /// :", this.anim);
    return this.anim ? 'start' : 'end';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  bascule() {
    this.anim = !this.anim;
  }
```

Template:

```
<app-centre [@startCentre]="quelEtatCentre" (click)="bascule()"></app-centre>
```

When i click "app-center", the opacity start 0.7 to  1.
Now I would like when the new visitor arrive in the page, I would like launch it automaticaly.

I try this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bascule();//would like opacity 0.7 wait  2 seconde for 1 
  }
```

When I enter or refesh the page, my "app-center" is not wait 0.7 => 1 opacity, the opacity is right now at 1.
How i must do for call without click en new enter the page ?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8uale)

Comment: Could you setup a demo please. It's easier to debug for us

Comment: ok, try insert stackbiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick and easy fix would be to put a setTimeout:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() =>
      this.bascule(), 1200);
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4471x)

Answer (score 0):

this is an example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8uale?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

the manual opacity:
the visitor click manual => click to button => the message opacity wille 0.7 to 1 css

the visitor enter à new page, I will want message is opacité 0.7 , and after 2 seconde wille opacity css will 1.